# Dependency errors in Angular when creating an $http interceptor as a standalone module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-module, angular-http-interceptors

Here is a working example of how I have set up an interceptor which attaches an authentication token to each request (this is more or less the example from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
angular.module("app", [])
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push("authInterceptor");
})
.factory("authInterceptor", function ($q) {
  return {
  // interceptor configuration here
  }
})
```

I have a lot of other stuff in my `config` and `run` blocks which call and initiate services from different angular modules, so I want to tidy things up a bit. However I understand there are some very specific rules to dependency injection in `config` blocks, which I don't quite understand, and these are preventing me from defining my `authInterceptor` factory in a separate module. As other logic in the `config` and `run` blocks calls other modules in the app, declaring that interceptor right there looks out of place.

This is what I want to do:

```
angular.module("services.authInterceptor", [])
.factory("authInterceptor", function ($q) {
  return {
  // interceptor configuration here
  }
});

angular.module("app", [
 "services.authInterceptor"
]).config(function ($httpProvider, authInterceptor) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push("authInterceptor");
});

// Error: Unknown provider authInterceptor.
```

I tried injecting it to the `run` block instead, but I guess you're not allowed to inject `$httpProvider` there:

```
angular.module("app", [
  "services.authInterceptor"
]).run(function ($httpProvider, authInterceptor) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push("authInterceptor");
});

// Error: Unknown provider: $httpProviderProvider <- $httpProvider
```

Where should I inject the module so that `$httpProvider` is also injectable, and where should I add the interceptor to existing ones? My main goal is keeping the interceptor and other similar services in their own self-containing modules.

**EDIT**

I get a different error which seems to be getting me closer when I declare a `provider` instead of `factory` (for some reason I always thought these were interchangeable):

```
angular.module("services.authInterceptor")
.provider("authInterceptor", function ($q) {
  return {}
})

// Error: Unknown provider: $q
```

So it now successfully injects `authInterceptor` to my `config` block, but fails when trying to find `$q`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

During the configuration phase only providers and constants can be injected. This is to prevent instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.

This is why you register interceptors by name (pushing the name as a string into the `$httpProvider.interceptors` array). They will be resolved later during runtime.

This is exactly what you did in your working example, and what you need to do in your second, even when the interceptor is in another module:

```
angular.module("services.authInterceptor", [])
.factory("authInterceptor", function ($q) {
  return {
  // interceptor configuration here
  }
});

angular.module("app", ["services.authInterceptor"])
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/A8SgJ87GOBk6mpXsoFuZ?p=preview

Comment: Perfect! So is this a general rule in config blocks, that I can call services by string if I want them resolved later? Or does it only apply to adding interceptors?

Comment: No - no general rule. Just a short explanation of why it works like this in this case :)

Comment: @tasseKATT thanks for this thread. I am getting the exact same problem after I minify & concat my app/**/*.js in one .min file. I tried ur exact steps, but start gettigng error what Elise got. I am stuck.

Comment: Hmm, really hard to tell what the problem is without seeing the code.

Comment: I just burned hours trying to configure my interceptor as a provider, all while doing this the whole time. Thank you SO MUCH for your knowledge.